# Selector from string in template

Tags: angular

I have an array of few selectors of different components in my app. 
In the template I want to iterate on that array and place each selector.
Can it be done?

Comment: yes it sure can

Comment: What do you mean by "place each selector"? This smells like a bad practice

Comment: Sounds like you want to bring other HTML and CSS files belong to other components.Check this out https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader